# CSS select class that is not with a prefix

Tags: css

I have the following anchor with classes:

```
a.text-primary
a
a.text-muted
```

How do I select a class that has no `text-`? Something like this:

```
a:not(.text-)
```

But of course the code above obviously doesn't work.

Comment: read about attribute selector

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) is what you are looking for. Especially `[attr^=value]`:

> Represents elements with an attribute name of attr whose value is prefixed (preceded) by value.

This should work:

```css
a:not([class^="text-"]) {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<a class="text-a">a</a>
<a class="b">b</a>
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/woeht3Lg/)

More example from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```css
a {
  color: blue;
}

/* Internal links, beginning with "#" */
a[href^="#"] {
  background-color: gold;
}

/* Links with "example" anywhere in the URL */
a[href*="example"] {
  background-color: silver;
}

/* Links with "insensitive" anywhere in the URL,
   regardless of capitalization */
a[href*="insensitive" i] {
  color: cyan;
}

/* Links with "cAsE" anywhere in the URL, 
with matching capitalization */ 
a[href*="cAsE" s] { 
  color: pink; 
}

/* Links that end in ".org" */
a[href$=".org"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#internal">Internal link</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://example.com">Example link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#InSensitive">Insensitive internal link</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://example.org">Example org link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Not working. It selects all.

Comment: It works when I changed it to `a:not([class*="text-"])`

Comment: Ah, I know why it works with `*`, because of the space. Thanks!

Comment: `*` is to check for contains